# Spring redirect with cookies attached

Tags: java, spring, redirect, cookies

Is there a way to set a cookie for a website I'm trying to redirect to? I'm trying to use Spring redirect to achieve this but I think I'm doing something work (or this is not possible at all)

Here's the method I have tried to use:

```
    @GetMapping("/redirect")
    public void redirect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        Cookie testCookie = new Cookie("test-cookie", "blah");

        testCookie.setDomain("something.com");
        testCookie.setPath("/");

        response.addCookie(testCookie);

        response.sendRedirect("https://something.com/test.html");

    }
```

I can see the "set-cookie" header but no actual cookie seems to be set in my browser.

M

Comment: Any updates here?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same problem. My case was to pass redirect from backend to frontend with attached cookies. Within one main domain. There's no success with code

```
cookie.path = "/"
cookie.domain = "domain.com"
cookie.maxAge = 60
cookie.isHttpOnly = false
response.addCookie(cookie)
```

But everything run when I changed to

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "customCookie=value; Path=/; Max-Age=60; Domain=domain.com")
```

**Important: cross-domain cookie passing will be blocked by browser**